# Cannot find the ONNX file specified using WinML

Tags: c#, windows-10, onnx, windows-machine-learning

I am trying to load an ONNX model using WinML, with the following code:

```
private async Task InitializeModelAsync()
{
    var path = @"ms-appx:///Assets/FER-Emotion-Recognition.onnx";
    var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(path));
    model = await CNTKGraphModel.CreateCNTKGraphModel(file);
}
```

The project compiles OK, but during run-time I am getting a *System.IO.FileNotFoundException*:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

I double checked but the file is indeed in the right folder. What did I do wrong?

Comment: do you set the file as Content?

Comment: Try to copy the file to LocalFolder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on your `onnx` file, go to the Properties panel and set its Build Action to Content.

Then, set the Copy to Output Directory to Copy if newer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

See [Get started with Machine Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/labs/insiderdevtour2018/machinelearning/index?ocid=idt_labs_cta_web2lab_machinelearning&tutorial-step=3)